# Adjacency matrix of a line graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that $G'$ is a line graph of $G$. How can we calculate the adjacency matrix of $G$ if we have adjacency matrix for the graph $G'$ ?

Comment: L(G) = laplacian of the graph = adjacency matrix minus diag.  matrix of degrees $d_{ii}$ ? How can it be equal to the adjacency matrix (unless no pair of vertices are connected ...) ?

Comment: Notation is misleading: $G'$ is a graph; $L(G)$ is a matrix.

Comment: I corrected the question

Comment: What do you mean by "is a line graph of $G$" ?

Comment: Line graph  formally $L(G)$ of a graph $G$ is a graph whose vertices represents the edges of $G$ and two vertices of $L(G)$ are connected if the edges they represent are adjacent. Here is the wiki link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph

Comment: Let's assume a simpler case. I would like to calculate the degrees of vertices of G. How can we do it the easiest way ?